# Is it possible to lose experience?

Tags: nuclear-dawn

I seem to be doing really really bad, but one thing I've noticed is that experience earned on the battlefield can be put towards little bonuses.  What they are, I'm not sure, as I haven't unlocked any yet, but I'm hopeful.

Is it possible for me to lose ground on my trek to these bonuses?  *Can I lose experience?*

Comment: Rep padding? lol or did you find the answer immediately?

Comment: @Foxtrot http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: Ah okay lol makes sense.

Comment: @JohntheGreen it's somewhat polite to allow others to come up with an answer rather than having a pre-made one you post 31 seconds after asking.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.  Fun fact: you can also go negative.

[image]

**[This is apparently a bug:](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4128904#4128904)**

> exp going backwards isn't a normal case.

Comment: Adding the actual cause of XP loss: The only way to lose XP is suicide, so without trying, you won't have to bother about it much. There will be the occasional suicide from standing below a spawning building or getting stuck in spawns, but it's usually so minor that it won't matter.

Comment: @dbemerlin Er, I've only suicided once or twice....not very much.

Comment: @JohntheGreen when the game can not connect to steam you get numbers like that

Comment: @Blem Then quitting Steam and reopening should fix it right?  Because Steam won't open without a connection?  Well, it didn't.  I restarted Steam and I've lost 50 more experience.