# Does killing bots count toward my stats?

Tags: nuclear-dawn

If I follow the instructions [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/61254/5029) to play on my own with a bunch of bots, will this affect my stats?

Will kills, deaths, headshots, etc, be added to my numbers like normal?

Answer (score 3):

Nope.  After half an hour of bot killing, my kill count had not increased from 0.

[image]

Also [confirmed by a dev](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4128692#4128692):

> bot kills do not count

**However:** after a second game, my kills were still at 0, but my deaths, captures, and teamwork had increased. My experience had increased by 19, but [that appears to be buggy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/61360/5029), so I'm not sure if it came from the bots or not, or if I even actually *earned* it.

It also appears that bots *will* count towards achievements.

Comment: Did you still get the XP though?

Comment: @Ace I didn't look at my XP before the game. I will test this.